# Covert Nginx Block to AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, aws-application-load-balancer

I am migration an Nginx server (was runnign to forward to requests to multiple docker containers) to AWS Application Load Balancer. one Location block of the nginx is as follow:

```
 location ~ /login/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass         http://docker-rest/$1;
        proxy_redirect     off;
    }
```

in the ALB I have simply create a target group that listens on the proper port (8080) and make the ALB listener rule to forward all /login to this target group.

The application is not working as expected and I was not able to find the issue. My feeling so far says that the ALB config I did is not proper and does not match the Nginx configuration.
Question: is my ALB config correct ? does it match what is configured in Nginx ?

Comment: explain 'not working as expected'

Comment: I cannot explain that. there could be many reasons and the routing was suspicious. my backend service returns a 403. that's a keycloak backend